# Flutter : init called

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to work on my fantasy app, and the app is working fine, but as soon as I open the keyboard to type something, I'm getting a message in debug console as **"I/flutter (30431): init called"**, which I'm not sure what it is about. So I just want to know what exactly is happening here.
[I'm adding the picture of my Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUkOp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just Information message that Flutter engine initiate invoking some internal methods to start the keyboard showing and interacting.

No big thing just for flutter team debug purposes and to you for knowing when the keyboard has displayed on screen, Don't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with flutter, but I looked up the issue and found this thread on github. So all rights go to rrousselGit, and his solution.

[Here is the link to read more:](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks/issues/149)

But he said, that **the dispose order is not reversed when the keys of a hook change.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).